# View All Data uncheck broken?

Tags: permissions, profile

If for a profile in the System Permissions I check "View All Data" I can see that the View All Permission has been enabled for all objects in Objects Settings.
If I go back to System Permissions and uncheck "View All Data" in the Object Settings nothing changes and View All permission is still enabled for all objects.

Is this a normal behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When checking the View All Data permission that means that all objects must have the View All permission so it checks them for you.

When you uncheck the View All Data permission that doesn't necessarily mean you want to remove all the View All permissions from the objects.

I don't think Salesforce persists how the View All (or any other) permission got set originally - manually by the user or automatically due to a dependency. Therefore it doesn't want to undo anything that you may have done manually.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. Actually I expected the View All Data to work on a parallel level from the View All permission on all object.

Comment: By unchecking it you are removing that permission from the profile so you can then have more granular control of the dependant permissions it grants. But in terms of it unchecking things it previously checked - correct, it doesn't do that.